# Calling closest fitting method

Tags: java, reflection, dynamic-languages

As part of developing a small ScriptEngine, I reflectively call java methods. A call by the script engine gives me the object the method name and an array of arguments. To call the method I tried to resolve it with a call to Class.getMethod(name, argument types).
This however only works when the classes of the arguments and the classes expected by the Method are the same.

```
Object o1 = new Object();
Object out = System.out;
//Works as System.out.println(Object) is defined
Method ms = out.getClass().getMethod("println",o1.getClass());
Object o2 = new Integer(4);
//Does not work as System.out.println(Integer) is not defined
Method mo = out.getClass().getMethod("println",o2.getClass());
```

I would like to know if there is a "simple" way to get the right method, if possible with the closest fit for the argument types, or if I have to implement this myself.

Closest fit would be:

```
Object o1 = new Integer(1);
Object o2 = new String("");
getMethod(name, o1.getClass())//println(Object)
getMethod(name, o2.getClass())//println(String)
```

**Update:**
To clarify what I need: 
The Script Engine is a small project I write in my free time so there are no strikt rules I have to follow. So I thought that selecting methods called from the Engine the same way the java compiler selects methods at compile time only with the dynamic type and not the static type of the Object would work.(with or without autoboxing)
This is what I first hoped that the Class.getMethod() would solve. But the Class.getMethod() requires the exact same Classes as argument types as the Method declares, using a subclass will result in a no such method Exception. This may happen for good reasons, but makes the method useless for me, as I don't know in advance which argument types would fit.
An alternate would be to call Class.getMethods() and iterate through the returned array and try to find a fitting method. This would however be complicated if I don't just want to take the first "good" method which I come across, so I hoped that there would be an existing solution which at least handles:

- closest fit: If arg.getClass() ==
  subclass and methods m(Superclass),
  m(Subclass) then call m(Subclass)
- variable arguments:
  System.out.printf(String ,String...)

Support for autoboxing would be nice, too.
If a call cannot be resolved it may throw an exception ( ma(String,Object), ma(Object, String), args= String,String)
(If you made it till here, thanks for taking the time to read it:-))

Comment: first define strict rules for "closest", then implementation is a detail.

Comment: just what I was wondering, too.
But for all the pedantically-correct answerers saying, "Define closest", I've got an easy one: the one that Java normally would choose (I guess at class-load).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out there is no standard method that does this, so you are going to have to implement your own overload resolution algorithm.

It would probably make sense to follow javac's overload resolution rules as closely as possible:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#292575
You can probably ignore generics for a dynamically-typed scripting language, but you might still benefit from the [bridge methods](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#What%20is%20a%20bridge%20method?) that the compiler generates automatically.

Some pitfalls to watch out for:

- `Class.isAssignableFrom` does not know about automatic widening primitive conversions, because these are syntactic sugar implemented in the compiler; They do not occur in the VM or class hierarchy.  e.g. `int.class.isAssignableFrom(short.class)` returns `false`.
- Similarly `Class.isAssignableFrom` does not know about auto-boxing.  `Integer.class.isAssignableFrom(int.class)` returns `false`.
- `Class.isInstance` and `Class.cast` take an `Object` as an argument; You cannot pass primitive values to them.  They also return an `Object`, so they cannot be used for unboxing (`(int) new Integer(42)` is legal in Java source but `int.class.cast(new Integer(42))` throws an exception.)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you use [`getMethods()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods()). It returns an array of all public methods (`Method[]`).

The most important thing here is:
"**If the class declares multiple public member methods with the same parameter types, they are all included in the returned array.**"

What you will then need to do is to **use the results** in this array to **determine** which one of them (if any) are the closest match. Since what the closest match should be depends very much on your requirements and specific application, it does make sense to code it yourself.

---

Sample code illustrating one approach of how you might go about doing this:

```
public Method getMethod(String methodName, Class<?> clasz)
{
    try
    {
        Method[] methods = clasz.getMethods();
        for (Method method : methods)
        {
            if (methodName.equals(method.getName()))
            {
                Class<?>[] params = method.getParameterTypes();
                if (params.length == 1)
                {
                    Class<?> param = params[0];
                    if ((param == int.class) || (param == float.class) || (param == float.class))
                    {
                        //method.invoke(object, value);
                        return method;
                    }
                    else if (param.isAssignableFrom(Number.class))
                    {
                        return method;
                    }
                    //else if (...)
                    //{
                    //    ...
                    //}
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //some handling
    }
    return null;
}
```

In this example, the `getMethod(String, Class<?>)` method will return a method that with only one parameter which is an `int`, `float`, `double`, or a superclass of `Number`.

This is a rudimentary implementation - It returns the first method that fits the bill. You would need to extend it to create a list of all methods that match, and then sort them according to some sort of criteria, and return the best matching method.

You can then take it even further by creating the more general `getMethod(String, Class<?>)` method, to handle more of the possible "close match" scenarios, and possibly even more than one paramter

HTH

---

Edit: As @finnw has pointed out, be careful when using [`Class#isAssignableFrom(Class<?> cls)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)), due to its limitations, as I have in my sample code, testing the primitives separately from the `Number` objects.

Comment: @bguiz, nice solution. Just want to add that you can test for `Class.isPrimitive()` and `Class.isArray()` to work around some of the limitations of isAssignableFrom(). @finnw's answer too.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no simple way to do this kind of thing.  Certainly, there's nothing in the standard Java class libraries to do this.

The problem is that there is no single "right" answer.  You need to consider all of your use-cases, decide what the "right method" should be and implement your reflection code accordingly.